# How to prevent batching of my alarm in Android?

Tags: android, alarm

I set an alarm to trigger in 2 minutes but the alarm
always goes off in about 5 minutes instead. I can see through adb output that the schedule is changed so that the alarm will go off with other system alarms.

Is there a way to enforce my 2 minutes?

I read this batching of alarms only started happening with API 19 and above however I am using API 16 and have tried changing TargetSDKVersion to 16 but it had no effect.

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 120 * 1000, alarmIntent);
```

"adb shell dumpsys alarm" output

```
ELAPSED_WAKEUP #1: Alarm{428be648 type 2 com.example.adrian.notifier}
type=2 when=+4m24s957ms repeatInterval=0 count=0
```

Comment: Have your figured out this issue? This problem is killing me..

have two alarms one is every 12seconds and the other is every 10minutes.. What happens is the two alarms fires at every 10 minutes so they are in batch..  This is insane..